# Run Android app on PC but outside of Emulator screen

Tags: windows, android-emulator, emulators

I know we can Android apps on PC using emulator like Andy or Bluestack.

What I really want to know if there's a way to run the app using the emulator but outside of Emulator screen.

For example - I use fooview app which floats on screen and I want to run that on PC. Using the emulators, I'm able to run it but only inside the emulator's screen not PC GUI.

Answer (score 0):

The fooview app appear to be using a combination of [Android Accessibility](https://support.google.com/accessibility/android/answer/6006564?hl=en) and SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW (system overlay) permission. Unfortunately such features are Android only an have no knowledge of what is going on outside of the emulator.

You should look for a Windows app which provides similar features for your version of Windows. Asking for such recommendation is off-topic for this site.